# What happens if a LLC Member fills out the LLC license with Malicious intent in the state of Mississippi

Tags: business, partnership, limited-liability-company

If There are 2 members of a LLC and a verbal agreement in which one Partner has 65% of the company and the other Partner had 35% of the company but the Partner with 35% of the company set up the LLC with him being President without his knowledge Does the Partner with 65% still have 65% of the company and if the company splits what rights does he have to any assets, income, or services purchased or made by the company

Comment: You don't have to be a majority shareholder to be president. I was the president of an LLC and had a 10% share. Some LLC's have whole management structures that have no ownership interest at all. The rights to assets, income, etc are all spelled out in the partnership agreement you should have signed before starting the LLC.

Comment: How is it possible for the minority member to set up the LLC "without the knowledge" of the majority member? You'll have to provide more information.